# Simple Arithmetic Puzzle 7. Or is it?

Tags: mathematics

The Arithmetic Puzzles are finally back! The break I took was longer than expected...

Let's start easy then.

> \begin{align}6\times8&=72\\10\times9&=6\\1\times1&=1\\18\times69&=\,?\end{align}

Can you find the value of the question mark?

Comment: maybe the lateral thinking tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> $5589$

Because

> You need to see the multiplication upside-down, (:
>  Hence, $69 \times 81 = 5589$

Comment: Is it rotate the first operand and mirror the second?

Comment: @James You should ROT13(Ebgngr 180 Qrterrf gur Yrsg-Unaq-Fvqr)